# On the calculation of the radiation from a gray body

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, equilibrium

To my understanding, nearly all results obtained on thermal radiation are based on two requirements: thermal equilibrium and more importantly, radiative exchange equilibrium.  Only in the case of no thermal conduction and convection, are the two requirements equivalent.  Right?

In thermal equilibrium, a black body can radiate black body radiation, which satisfies the Planck radiation formula and Stefan-Boltzmann's law. But only when the two requirements both hold, black bodies and gray bodies satisfy Kirchhoff's law of thermal radiation. Right?

I found in several places that the radiative heat transfer between two gray bodies (such as the human body, the earth's surface, etc) at different temperatures can be calculated according to Stefan-Boltzmann's law by multiplying a gray body factor (or equivalently absorptivity).

In my opinion, the human body itself is in thermal equilibrium at a temperature of about 300K, but it does not in thermal equilibrium with its thermal radiation. Why can we use Stefan-Boltzmann's law to calculate its thermal radiation?

Comment: I don't follow the premise of your question. A blackbody need not absorb as much radiation as it emits. But it would then need some other heat source to be in thermal equilibrium.

Comment: @ProfRob Thank you, I modified my question. Yes, I know that a true black body can emit black body radiation if it is in thermal equilibrium.  What I mean here is the black body radiation emitted by analog black bodies such as a cavity in thermal equilibrium and radiative exchange equilibrium.

Comment: Perhaps you need to explain what is meant by radiative exchange equilibrium.